# Codename one-hardware Native back button to go previous page

Tags: java, codenameone

In a Codename one app, how do we establish the back command from the native, the hardware back button on the device, to go back to previous form?
Most androids have a native back button, but when I press it in the app, it does not go in the previous form, it minimizes the app.
I have tried through constants in the .res file, I have not found a relevant option.
(The red underlined button, bottom left in this image)

Added: All forms are created using the new GUI builder.

[image: the red lined]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also struggling with the back command, here is how it works (in my opinion) :

Let's say that you have FormA and FormB. You launch FormB from FormA and when you press back button in FormB, FormA shows back.

To do this : In FormA, declare this command :

```
Command back = new Command("Back") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        showBack();
    }
};
```

Still in FormA, in the actionEvent of the button or something else that launches FormB :

```
public void onFormActionEvent(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
    Form formB = new FormB();
    formB.getToolbar().setBackCommand(back);
    formB.setBackCommand(back);
    formB.show();
}
```

It works for me and it's the only way I manage to run the back command.

Comment: I put in in my application.java, not working so far.
I should note that all forms are created using the new GUI builder.

Comment: Contact is FormB, this code is in Main (FormA)

 public void onContactActionEvent(com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent ev) {
            Form Contact = new Contact();
          Contact.getToolbar().setBackCommand(back);
    Contact.setBackCommand(back);
     new Contact().show();
    }

Comment: Your **Main** is the first class that is launched ? With `init()`, `start()` ... ? If so, it is not a form. You have to launch your FormA in `start()` and then in FormA class put the code I wrote.

Comment: @Deveray .. I was going to try your approach, but I am getting an error message: The method showBack() is undefined for the type new Command(){}. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @rainer I haven't use Codename One for a while so I don't remember everything. The method `showBack() ` is method of `Form` so be sure to be in a Form when you call it.

Comment: @Deveray, thanks for the reply. Got it figured out in the meantime. Thanks again ..

Answer (score 2):

If you use something like:

```
myForm.getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> showPreviousForm());
```

It would work correctly by implicitly placing the arrow on the top left and handling the physical back button.

If you just want the physical back button on devices that have it you can do that using:

```
myForm.setBackCommand(new Command("") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        showPreviousForm();
    }
});
```

Notice I'm referring to the hardward button as it looks the same for the app as the on-screen back button on the bottom.

Comment: tried in Myapplication.java, and changed "myform" to form names.
Displays errors. Should i create a new class for previous form?

 public void init(Object context) {
        // use two network threads instead of one
        updateNetworkThreadCount(2);

        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);
        
        myForm.getToolbar().setBackCommand("", e -> showPreviousForm());
        
        myForm.setBackCommand(new Command("") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        showPreviousForm();

Comment: Is there a working example, of forms created by user, with the hardware back button enabled? In the demos there are only forms created in myapplication.java class.

Comment: No you need to declare the form object final or in the class. Notice you can test it in the simulator by pressing the escape button which simulates the physical back button on all skins. You can place a breakpoint in the debugger and see that the code is reached when you press back.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I am getting the following error message: The method showPreviousForm() is undefined for the type new Command(){}

Comment: It's a method you need to write that will show the previous form.

Answer (score 1):

try this

for example
this for your own button

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override public void onClick(View view) {
 onBackPressed(); 
} });
```

this for use device back button

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

this for use your own button

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             finish();
         }
     });
```

Comment: I am looking to implement the back method on device/hardware back button.